# Wordpress custom leftjoin on two tables

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I'm new to the idea of left-joining.

I have created two custom tables within my wordpress database. One detail (containing leads) and one storing car dealers.

When I send a lead to a cardealer, I store the ID of the cardealer into a column "sent_to" in my detail table. So now I want to show which car dealers have received each lead.

And here comes the leftjoin:

```
global $wpdb;

$cardealers = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT detail.name, cardealers.user_id
    FROM detail
    LEFT JOIN cardealers ON  cardealers.user_id = detail.sent_to"
);
```

And this is how I currently try to input my results:

```
foreach($cardealers as $cardealer) {
    $name = $row->name;
    echo $name;
}
```

But as you can guess, nothing really happens.

Hope that somebody can help.

Comment: Are you missing WordPress database prefix on custom tables ?
What happen when you run this query in SQL ?

Comment: My custom tables doesn't have the prefix